# What is the purpose of Reflect.get method's third parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am just learning Proxy and Reflect in ES6. But there is a problem make me confused.There is an optional parameter called receiver in Reflect.get method, but how to use this parameter? Can anyone give me some examples.
[image]

The document on MDN said receiver is the value of this provided for the call to target if a getter is encountered. When used with Proxy, it can be an object that inherits from target. I just can not understand what it means and the example code is not clear enough to understand too.

Answer (score 2):

Proxies aside (I don't know if that's the best example to focus on), the receiver is only really relevant (and used) when dealing with *accessor properties*.

A property is either a data property (the value of the property is language value) or an accessor property (the property has getters and/or setters).

Example:

```js
var obj = {
    foo: 42,    // data property
    get bar() { // accessor property
      return 21;
    },
};

console.log(obj.foo, obj.bar);
```

The `receiver` value is used if the property you are trying to access is an accessor property. `this` inside the getter (or setter) will then refer to the receiver value:

```js
var obj = {
  bar: 42,
  get foo() {
    return this.bar;
  }
};

console.log(Reflect.get(obj, 'foo', {bar: 21}));
```

See [`OrdinaryGet` in the ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryget).

---

This is probably something that is rarely needed in user code but might be useful in framework/library code.